# RNA-seq STAR alignment error in reading fastq files

Tags: bash

I am writing a script to use the STAR aligner to map fastq files to a reference genome. Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
#$ -N DT_STAR
#$ -l mem_free=200G
#$ -pe openmp 8
#$ -q bio,abio,pub8i

module load STAR/2.5.2a


cd /dfs1/bio/dtatarak/DT-advancement_RNAseq_stuff/RNAseq_10_4_2017

mkdir David_data1


STAR  --genomeDir /dfs1/bio/dtatarak/indexes/STAR_Index --readFilesIn /dfs1/bio/dtatarak/DT-advancement_RNAseq_stuff/RNAseq_10_4_2017/DT_1_read1.fastq 
/dfs1/bio/dtatarak/DT-advancement_RNAseq_stuff/RNAseq_10_4_2017/DT_1_read2.fastq --runThreadN 8 --outFileNamePrefix "David_data1/DT_1"`
```

I keep getting this error message

EXITING because of fatal input ERROR: could not open readFilesIn=/dfs1/bio/dtatarak/DT-advancement_RNAseq_stuff/RNAseq_10_4_2017/DT_1_read1.fastq

Does anyone have experience using STAR? I cannot figure out why it isn't able to open my read files.

Answer (score 0):

The second space character between `STAR` and `--genomeDir` is a syntax error. There should be only one.

Another thing is the argument `--outFileNamePrefix "David_data1/DT_1"`

Are you sure, that it takes a path, which is in quotes? Also you have to create the directory `DT_1` within `David_data1` first, if you didn't do so already manually. Also there always have to be a `/` in front of the paths.

```
--outFileNamePrefix /David_data1/DT_1/
```

Besides, are there any subdirectories in your `STAR_Index` folder? Because I always have to set the `genomDir` argument like this:

```
--genomeDir path/to/STAR_index/STARindex/hg38/
```

The message is known to come up, after syntax errors, so I hope it works, if you try it something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#$ -N DT_STAR
#$ -l mem_free=200G
#$ -pe openmp 8
#$ -q bio,abio,pub8i

module load STAR/2.5.2a


cd /dfs1/bio/dtatarak/DT-advancement_RNAseq_stuff/RNAseq_10_4_2017

mkdir David_data1
cd David_data1
mkdir DT_1
cd ..


STAR --genomeDir /dfs1/bio/dtatarak/indexes/STAR_Index --readFilesIn /dfs1/bio/dtatarak/DT-advancement_RNAseq_stuff/RNAseq_10_4_2017/DT_1_read1.fastq 
/dfs1/bio/dtatarak/DT-advancement_RNAseq_stuff/RNAseq_10_4_2017/DT_1_read2.fastq --runThreadN 8 --outFileNamePrefix /David_data1/DT_1/
```